# show up sidebar from hover to button click

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar

So, I have hidden sidebar that will show up when mouse on hover it.

this is html code:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <img class="logo1" src="../img/logo1.png"><br><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS code:

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: 0.8s;
}

.sidenav:hover{
   width: 250px;
}
```

my question is, how do I change the hover to become click button to show up the sidebar. It will be used for mobile version, so when the web is open in small device it will automatically change the sidebar width to zero and appear a 'menu button'. the example is like in this link: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sidebar-responsive but mine is use hover first and I dont used jquery. it is possible? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS only by using `:target` instead of `:hover`.

```
.sidenav:target {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Now you only need an anchor link to set focus on the targeted element.

```
<a href="#mySidenav">Click</a>
```

Downside is that because your links also contain empty anchor links (the `#`), the sidebar will loose focus when they are clicked and will size down to it's original width.

Here's an example based on your code.
https://jsfiddle.net/PaulvdDool/rkxeyf1g/

Comment: what I mean is, when I open it from desktop, it will shows up the sidebar used hover, and if I open it from mobile device, the hover will turn off, and change with a button, and the sidebar has no width. or u can see the example from https://la24.org/ open the desktop and mobile version, you will see what I mean. thanks before

Comment: use different styling based on [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). :hover for large viewports and :target for smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
.sidenav a{ float:left; width:100%;}
.mobiletoggle img{ width:25px; height:25px; float:right;}
.mobiletoggle{ float:right; width:50px;  cursor:pointer;}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){.mobiletoggle{ display:none;}}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){.sidenav{ width:0px; }.sidenav.open{ width:100px; }}
```

Add this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('.mobiletoggle').on("click", function(e) {
$('.sidenav').toggleClass( "open" );
```

});

```
});
```

Add this html with ur code

```
<div class="mobiletoggle"><img src="../favicon.ico"></div>
```

It is running as like you given the ref. Just work to it let me know the comments.

Comment: yes the image is shows up when I open in mobile device, but when I click it, it didnt display the sidebar. why is that? thanks

Comment: can we do it with just CSS too? it is possible?

Comment: For which hover we have to show either the toggle img or somewhere